# How to delete rows in Python with CSV? (Issue is with output back into the right format)

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 5 columns and many many rows of data.

[image: table example]

I need to delete an entire row based on data in one column which I can do on my own.

My issue is I am unable to print the data back into the CSV format properly.

I'm importing the CSV like so.

```
data=open(datafile)  #this datafile variable has the CSV path
parse=csv.DictReader(data)
newfile= open("validated.csv", "w", newline="")#I'd like to output my changes in this new file and leave the original CSV as is 
output = csv.writer(newfile)
```

Based on what I've read my CSV in interpreted as many different dictionaries.

I've tried many different list, dictionary, and for loop combos but I just can't get it right.

```
def validate_profits(datafile):#this will remove non numeric profits rows so we can get a count of our useful dataset.
    data=open(datafile)  #Open then parse data.
    parse=csv.DictReader(data)
    newfile= open("validated.csv", "w", newline="")#New file for output. 
    output = csv.writer(newfile)
    outputlist=[]

    for rows in parse: #Looping through CSV files to check each profit column. 
        try:
            (float(rows["Profit (in millions)"]))#This is the validation for the Profit column
            outputlist.append(rows)
            

        except ValueError:
            pass
    counter=0
    while True:
        try:
            counter+=1
            output.writerows([[outputlist[counter]]])#Output the numericaly valid rows to a new file.
        except IndexError:
            break
    count_rows("validated.csv")

validate_profits ("data.csv")
```

Comment: It seem that you should use the writerow function instead of the writerows as you are writing one row at time in your loop. Also, change output.writerows([[outputlist[counter]]]) to output.writerows(outputlist[counter])

Answer (score 2):

If your sole job is "write only those rows with a valid numeric value in the Profit column", then it's just this:

```
def validate_profits(datafile):
    #this will remove non numeric profits rows so we can get a count of our useful dataset.
    data=open(datafile)  #Open then parse data.
    count = 0
    parse=csv.DictReader(data)
    newfile= open("validated.csv", "w", newline="")#New file for output. 
    output = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=parse.fieldnames)
    for row in parse:
        try:
            _ = float(rows["Profit (in millions)"])
            output.writerow(row)
            count += 1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return count
```

Many people would use a regular expression to test the contents of that field rather than relying on an exception from `float`, but this works.

Comment: Hi Tim, This was it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your function trying to fix some points and suggesting a somewhat more pythonic way to do what you want:

```
def validate_profits(datafile):
    with open(datafile, 'r', encoding='utf-8')as f:  #Open then parse data.
        parsed=csv.DictReader(f)
    with open("validated.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8'):
        output = csv.writer(newfile)
        outputlist=[]

    for row in parsed:
        try:
            (float(row["Profit (in millions)"]))
            outputlist.append(rows)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    output.writerows(outputlist)
```

Comment: Thanks, This is a great solution.